# How can I compare the order in which characters appear in excel?

Tags: excel-formula, sequence, string-matching, excel-365

The problem - I want to decide how similar two strings are based on the order in which the letters appear.

For instance, comparing the strings "Paul" and "JoPaul". JoPau has 2 extra characters and one missing character compared to Paul, and the characters which match are not in the same position (e.g. P is the first character in Paul, but the third in JoPau, a is the 2nd character and the 4th character and so on.

However, JoPau is more similar to Paul than the string JPuao. In JoPau, *a* follows *P*, and *u* follows *a*, the same as it does in Paul. However, none of the characters is followed by the 'correct' character in JPuao.

My current attempt:

> =LET(origname,$A$1,origchars,MID(origname,SEQUENCE(LEN(origname)),1),fuzzchars,MID(Table1[@Fuzzstring],SEQUENCE(LEN(Table1[@Fuzzstring])),1),sortorigchars,SORT(origchars),goodchars,FILTER(fuzzchars,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(fuzzchars,origname))),goodpos,SEARCH(goodchars,Table1[@Fuzzstring]),sortfuzzchars,SORT(fuzzchars),origpos,SEARCH(origchars,origname),nextorigchar,FILTER(MID(origname,origpos+1,1),LEN(MID(origname,origpos+1,1))>0),nextfuzzchar,FILTER(MID(Table1[@Fuzzstring],goodpos+1,1),LEN(MID(Table1[@Fuzzstring],goodpos+1,1))),nextfuzzchar=nextorigchar)

This does not work if one of the good characters is missing.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like Levenshtein distance is the wheel you are trying to reinvent. I would imagine there are quite a few VBA UDFs that folks have written that could spit back the edit distance of two words.

Comment: Power Query has fuzzy match option: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-fuzzy-match-power-query-ffdd5082-c0c8-4c8e-a794-bd3962b90649  Otherwise there are plugins available for fuzzy lookup https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011